# Get audio recording volume (UWP)

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm recording audio using `LowLagMediaRecording` . I want to check the volume in real time. Is there any way of doing that? Or an alternative way of recording that does allow me to check the volume?

I've checked both the `LowLagMediaRecording` and `MediaCapture` classes but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into WASAPI and APIs like `ActivateAudioInterfaceAsync`, `IAudioClient` and `IAudioCaptureClient`. You might need a C++/CX or C++/WinRT component to enable these unless there's a pre-wrapped WinRT version of these you'd rather use.